# Call field's function and pass &self in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, ownership

I have a `MainStruct` which owns an instance of `HelperStruct`. I want to make a method that calls `helper`'s method. But the `helper`'s method really needs (immutable) access to `MainStruct`

```rust
struct MainStruct {
    helper: HelperStruct,
}

impl MainStruct {
    pub fn call_helper(&mut self, args) { 
        // &mut self because the_method changes inner state of HelperStruct
        self.helper.the_method(self, args)
    }
}

impl HelperStruct {
    pub fn the_method(&mut self, owner: &MainStruct, args) {
        owner.other_method();
    }
}
```

With this setup, I'm getting

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.helper` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
214 |         self.helper.the_method(self, args)
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^----------^----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |         |           |            |
    |         |           |            immutable borrow occurs here
    |         |           immutable borrow later used by call
    |         mutable borrow occurs here
```

It is crucial that the `MainStruct` remains the primary interface for interaction with the functionality (so having Helper own Main isn't an option).

How should I restructure my code (or maybe use smart pointers?) so that I can interact with the owner from the inside of Helper?
Also, it is guaranteed that `the_method()` will only be called inside an instance of `MainStruct`.

#### Actual context:

The `MainStruct` is the `Field` of my game. The `HelperStruct` is the class that takes care of pathing, A* mostly. A* has a number of large arrays that store its state. After an A* pass only some of them *need* to be reinitialized (or otherwise cleaned).

I end up calling A* a lot of times, so I want to avoid fully reinitializing it for every pass. So I store it in `Field`, and only call `reset()` after a pass.

To path plan properly, A* needs to look at the `Field` (obstacles, etc). While the A* is going, it of course changes some of its own fields, so `the_method`, being actually

```rust
pub fn full_pathing(&mut self, field: &Field, source: (i32, i32), destination: (i32, i32))
```

needs to have a `&mut self`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convince Rust that, whatever `HelperStruct` is doing with `MainStruct`, it's not going to try to *also* access itself *through* `MainStruct`, since that constitutes an immutable reference to something that you also have a mutable reference to.

Depending on the complexity and needs of `HelperStruct`, one option would be to [`swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) a dummy `HelperStruct` value into `MainStruct` and then call the function on the (now-isolated) `HelperStruct`.

```
use std::mem::swap;

struct MainStruct {
    helper: HelperStruct,
}

impl MainStruct {
    pub fn call_helper(&mut self, args) { 
        let mut helper_struct = HelperStruct::default(); // Some dummy value
        swap(&mut helper_struct, &mut self.helper);
        helper_struct.the_method(self, args);
        swap(&mut helper_struct, &mut self.helper);
    }
}
```

This way, `HelperStruct.the_method` has immutable access to all of `MainStruct` *except* itself, which has been temporarily shimmed out. After we're done, we swap the values back and there's no harm done.

Comment: Thanks! If my Helper owns a number of large `Vector`s, will the `swap` take a while, or does it not depend on the content of the variable?

Comment: `swap` is going to swap the top-level memory. There's no need to do a deep copy, since anything owned by one of the arguments will still have exactly one owner after the swap. So how long the `swap` takes will depend on the [`size_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) your data type, which is constant for a vector and does not depend on the number of elements inside the vector.

Answer (score 3):

You can make `the_method` an associated function, and have it only receive a `&mut MainStruct`. It will have to access itself through that reference:

```
struct MainStruct {
    helper: HelperStruct,
}

impl MainStruct {
    pub fn call_helper(&mut self, args) { 
        HelperStruct::the_method(self, args)
    }
}

impl HelperStruct {
    pub fn the_method(main: &mut MainStruct, args) {
        main.other_method();

        //Access helper like this:
        main.helper.whatever();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if your two structs are so intertwined, you could combine them into a single struct.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `self` to `the_method` borrows `helper` immutably, but the method call itself also borrows it mutably. If you change the signature to

```rust
pub fn the_method(&self, owner: &MainStruct, args)
```

it should work. If you need `the_method` to take a mutable reference to self you'll need to think of restructuring your code.

Comment: yes, I need a mutable self in `the_method`. Can you recommend how to restructure my code?

Comment: Not without more context. One idea would be to call owner `owner.other_method()` directly from MainStruct. You could also look into `Rc<RefCell>`s, but I would recommend using something like that only after exhausting other options.

Comment: I have added context to my question. One solution I currently have in mind is to avoid storing A* in the Field. Instead, store them 'close' to each other in another struct, that currently owns Field, among other things. This, however, will complicate other code, so I'm still looking for advice!

Comment: I don't know your other code. But what I've found in my own code is that it's best to avoid thinking in a too object-oriented way when programming in Rust. It's often easier to pass dependencies into the functions that need them instead of trying to use structs as you would use objects in other languages. For example your `MainStruct` could have a `full_pathing` method and you could pass it a struct containing all the data that needs to be preserved between calls. That way you can fully avoid passing references to structs just to call methods on them.

Comment: That being said `Rc<RefCell>`s can be used to "delay" borrow checking until you actually need to access a variable. I've used them in the passed to covert some designs from object oriented languages, but they are not exactly idiomatic Rust and eventually I was able to get rid of them by restructuring.